# Are there replacement RF keys?

Tags: chrysler, key

I co-own a 2009 Chrysler 300. One of the keys no longer works. The RF electronics does not work so the alarm will not disarm but the mechanical lock stuff works.

My girlfriend was informed by the CHCH NZ agent that a replacement key will cost $1000. What was inside the key looked more like $20.

Is this for real?  Are the electronic keys for Chrysler 300 known to be unreliable? Are there any generic keys that could easily be programmed to work?

Comment: This is a little confusing. What is a "*CHCH NZ agent*"? Which type of key(s) do you have? Are you referring to the chip in the key or the remote keyless entry?

Comment: This is really bordering on an opinion based question, if not a shopping question. Would you want to show it some love which might help it out of this, Autistic?

Comment: My buddy and I replaced one (US model) for ~$20 online. I think it was the same model...

Comment: I suspect you will need to purchase a key, which can be found much cheaper than dealer, have someone cut it, but then you will need to have the dealer code it to the vehicle ( That is the case with my 2010 Chrysler ).  In the end its quite expensive but not $1000.

Comment: Might just be a dead battery. I'd try to change that first. NZ$1000 seems somewhat high. My BMW dealership will ask about €200 for a replacement key, 250 maybe incl. coding of the car.

Answer (score 2):

Frequently eBay and other shopping venues will have aftermarket keys.  However it will likely need programming which is where the new key unique ID number is recorded in the ECU.

That requires special electronic tools.  Usually the dealer has that equipment. Sometimes in larger cities there are automotive locksmiths who can do this.

You should find out the general procedure for your car so that you can shop better.  Also if there is a remote that is a different programming operation.

The dealer or locksmith may be willing to program your key. Usually the authorized replacement keys are much more then $20, one I priced from a dealer recently was $180.

Programming costs vary but $200 is not out of line.  I would only use someone who has experience doing this as it is possible with many cars to "brick" the ECU.